# Add values to a specific Tile in a Tilemap in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Is there a way to add values to a specific Tile in a Tilemap on Unity with c#? So that I can write and read it with the Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create your own Tile class inheriting from TileBase. The other option is to add a prefab to your tile preset, which will be instantiated with the Tile.

Comment: Could you give me a link which explains this more in detail or explain it by yourself?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/populate-tilemap-palette-with-custom-tilebase-class.547948/  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-ScriptableTiles-TileBase.html

Comment: This works but means all instances of the same tile have to not only have the same properties, but the same values. Which does allow arbitrary values on any tile

Answer (score -1):

writing here to help anyone else stuck with this issue. I was stuck for several days till I found the **last post** on this page.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/populate-tilemap-palette-with-custom-tilebase-class.547948/

This accomplished exactly what I wanted. Being able to add variables/data and functions to a Tile while still letting you use it in the Tile Palette editor.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32085053)

Comment: This means you are forced to have the same data and data values on all of a tile type. Which is not a good solution.

Comment: If you want different properties per tile, you need an associated gameobject. The performance benefits of using a tile system requires having only one instance per tile